# How to return raw string with ApiController?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an ApiController that serves XML/JSON, but I would like one of my actions to return pure HTML. I tried the below but it still return XML/JSON.

```
public string Get()
{
    return "<strong>test</strong>";
}
```

This is what the above returns:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;</string>
```

Is there a way to return just the pure, unescaped text without even the surrounding XML tags (maybe a different return type of action attribute)?

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You could have your Web Api action return an `HttpResponseMessage` for which you have full control over the Content. In your case you might use a StringContent and specify the correct content type:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            "<strong>test</strong>", 
            Encoding.UTF8, 
            "text/html"
        )
    };
}
```

or

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return base.ResponseMessage(new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            "<strong>test</strong>", 
            Encoding.UTF8, 
            "text/html"
        )
    });
}
```

Comment: I havent tried yet but I wonder if I'd set data type to html would work ?

Comment: No it won't work. The Web API has XML and JSON formatters built-in only. For everything else you will have to build your own formatter or return raw HttpResponseMessages from your methods as shown in my answer.

Comment: HttpResponseMessage is located in the System.Net.Http namespace.

Answer (score 12):

Another possible solution. In Web API 2 I used the base.Content() method of `APIController`:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post()
    {
        return base.Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {} , new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "text/plain");
    }
```

I needed to do this to get around an IE9 bug where it kept trying to download JSON content. This should also work for XML-type data by using the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` media formatter.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: the OP was asking for returning a html string .. where is such a string ? and how can JsonMediaTypeFormatter return html ?

Comment: thanks, I found your answer one step before wrinting my own MediaTypeFormatter for returning opaque plain strings, I wouldn't guess that JsonMediaTypeFormatter also handles text/plain

Answer (score 6):

Just `return Ok(value)` won't work, it will be threated as `IEnumerable<char>`.

Instead use `return Ok(new { Value = value })` or simillar.

Comment: return Ok(stringValue) worked fine for me. [c# webapi net5.0]

Comment: @theSushil: that might've been changed in .NET Core or .NET 5. The response is from 2016, the pre-.NET Core times where this was an issue.

Comment: For me, it almost worked - for JSON it escaped everything, rendering the json invalid.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MVC rather than WebAPI you can use the base.Content method:

```
return base.Content(result, "text/html", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

I call the following webapi2 controller method from an mvc controller method:

```
<HttpPost>
Public Function TestApiCall(<FromBody> screenerRequest As JsonBaseContainer) As IHttpActionResult
    Dim response = Me.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    response.Content = New StringContent("{""foo"":""bar""}", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
    Return ResponseMessage(response)
End Function
```

I call it from this routine on the asp.net server:

```
Public Async Function PostJsonContent(baseUri As String, requestUri As String, content As String, Optional timeout As Integer = 15, Optional failedResponse As String = "", Optional ignoreSslCertErrors As Boolean = False) As Task(Of String)
    Return Await PostJsonContent(baseUri, requestUri, New StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), timeout, failedResponse, ignoreSslCertErrors)
End Function

Public Async Function PostJsonContent(baseUri As String, requestUri As String, content As HttpContent, Optional timeout As Integer = 15, Optional failedResponse As String = "", Optional ignoreSslCertErrors As Boolean = False) As Task(Of String)
    Dim httpResponse As HttpResponseMessage

    Using handler = New WebRequestHandler
        If ignoreSslCertErrors Then
            handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function(sender, cert, chain, policyErrors) True)
        End If

        Using client = New HttpClient(handler)
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseUri) Then
                client.BaseAddress = New Uri(baseUri)
            End If

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
            client.Timeout = New TimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout).Ticks)

            httpResponse = Await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content)

            If httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim response = Await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response) Then
                    Return response
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

    Return failedResponse
End Function
```

Answer (score -3):

We must strive not to return html but pure data from our API's and format data accordingly in the UI, but maybe you can use:

```
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
     new{content=YourStringContent})
```

it works for me

Comment: Wrapping something in a dummy object does not make it any more pure. If the HTML _is_ your data, there's no sense in hiding it.

Comment: The idea of web api's is to return data, and leave the UI to add the required HTML, maybe we can have some cases where the data is HTML, but I think that is not the norm.

Comment: I agree that we should strive to return structured data instead of HTML.
however, the code you provided did not return raw string solely as requested