# Returned string from the server contains \t \r\n

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, asp.net-web-api

I have C# class that transforms XSLT to html using this code:

```
public class MyXslTransform
{
    public XslTransform(string styleSheetPath)
    {
        Xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        Xslt.Load(StyleSheetPath);
    }

    public string TransformToString(XmlDocument doc)
    {

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
            Xslt.Transform(reader, null, sw);
            string html = sw.ToString();
            return html;
        }
    }
    private XslCompiledTransform Xslt { get; set; }
}
```

I return the html string as a string type in the web controller. But when it arrives into the browser I get loads of : `\t \r\n \"` etc. How can I get rid of that encoding for newline, tab and so on.
In the browser I use AngularJS and a C# REST web api.

If I use this code instead in the `TransformToString` method:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        Xslt.Transform(doc.CreateNavigator(), writer);
        ms.Position = 0;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

I only get `\n`,`\t` and escaped double quotes `\"`

Method in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetHtmlFromXslt()
{
    return GetHtmlFromXmlAndXslt();
}
```

Comment: just for test. Can you write to file your result string. `return sr.ReadToEnd()` excnahge to `var temp = sr.ReadToEnd(); File.WriteAllText("1.txt", temp);`. Will "1.txt" file have \n, \t symbols?

Comment: It keeps the \r\n but not as visible characters but as spaces.. Maybe I shouldn't return it as string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would suggest to return that as a html rather than plain text (probably that is a reason why you are getting these symbols):

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetHtmlFromXslt()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent(GetHtmlFromXmlAndXslt());
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

If that is not possible you can replace unwanted strings before displaying like so:

```
yourHtml.replace(/\\n|\\r|\\t/g, '') //will replace \n, \t and \r
```

Comment: How do I return it as a html? I have a REST API, not an ASP.NET page, the string/html returned gets appended in angularJS upon arrival.

Comment: @A.K maybe you need to set content type **Response.ContentType = "text/html";**.

Comment: I have added my function which resides in a ApiController subclass that I have made

Comment: haha, I have just found that here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046417/how-to-return-raw-string-with-apicontroller

Comment: I'd also return `IHttpActionResult` for easier migration to ASP.NET 6 in the future