# I can't pass a raw body without receiving a null response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I've just finished following this tutorial:
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/13/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-with-ASPNET-Web-API#CapturingtherawRequestBody

And I'm trying to accomplish the trivial task of sending an abstract/raw request body without the stupid/useless middle layer in ASP.NET trying to interpret the body contents as a pre-defined class I've already created.

Here's my super simple code ASP.NET seems to %$#& up:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public string test([FromBody] string json)
{
    return json;
}
```

Which would lead you to think that POSTing to this URI with the following body:
`"trouble shooting fun"` OR `"{"info":"troubleshooting fun"}"`

would simply result in this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4

{"info":"troubleshooting fun"}
```

This is the kind of response you'd expect from all the other web frameworks like Django or Ruby-o-Rails because it just makes sense, but in ASP.NET Web API there is an additional layer working behind the scenes that forces you to create the request and response objects manually by declaring them as local classes like so:

```
public class hardCodedRequestJson
{
    public string keyValuePair { get; set; }
}
```

So... ummm this is kind of cool, if you want some useless backwards compatibility with XML but this approach comes at the cost of being stuck with extremely specific parameters for each API call, for my situation I'd have to make hundreds of different combinations of classes and functions that account for the dynamic number of possibilities the client must have when making an API call to the server.

How could I feed any kind of JSON object I wanted into an ASP.NET Web API controller and get that EXACT json I requested back as a response??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14046417/34397

Comment: nice, looks good for returning any JSON I want, but still doesn't resolve how to POST any JSON I want.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a pretty clean way to do it, although it feels extremely akward:

```
public async Task<string> PostRawBufferManual()
{
    string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Will allow you to formulate a request like so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET *farting noise"
Date: Tue, 05 May 2015 23:37:21 GMT
Content-Length: 30

"{\"info\":\"This simple task took longer than it should've\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass message formatting, you need to use the message types directly.

Accept an `HttpRequestMessage` as a parameter and `await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.
Then, return an `HttpResponseMessage` with your body & content type.

Comment: I don't understand. How would you convert the incoming RequestMessage into a ResponseMessage?

Comment: Read the content as a string (or byte array), then pass it to the HttpResponseMessage