# Outputting html with OWIN selfhost

Tags: c#, owin, self-hosting

I'm experimenting with OWIN selfhost, and I'm trying to output a html response, however the server is always returning xml output. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Index()
    {
        return "<b>kg</b>";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new StartOptions();
        options.Urls.Add("http://+:8181");

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server started");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046417/how-to-return-raw-string-with-apicontroller how to return HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

You're using WebApi (ApiController). This is for producing xml or JSON, not html. MVC controllers that produce HTML do not work in selfhost until you move to ASP.NET Core.